# Insert en tabla Informix desde un script

Tags: linux, bash, insert, informix

Necesito al crear usuarios y grupos insertarlos en la base de datos en sus respectivas tablas, si escribo la línea no tengo problema, ahora si estoy en un script, al utilizar las variables me da error, les dejo el script y la estructura de la tabla:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Ingrese el nombre del grupo a crear: " grupo
groupadd $grupo
gid=$(grep -w "$grupo" /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3)
echo "ID DEL GRUPO CREADO :" $gid
echo "insert into rol (id_rol, nombre, borrado) values ($gid, '$grupo', 'f')" | dbaccess mibase


create table rol (
    id_rol integer not null,
    nombre varchar (50) unique not null,
    borrado boolean not null,
    primary key (id_rol)

);
```

como dije, si tiro directamente: `echo "insert into empleado (id_rol, nombre, borrado) values (123, 'administrativo', 'f')" | dbaccess mibase` funciona bien, pero el ejemplo ese me da error en el caracter 51, que es el "$" del "gid", lo que recibe es un número, y el campo en que lo quiero cargar es un integer por eso no comillas. Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué error te da exactamente?